# TestNG: ClassCastException when returning Iterator in DataProvider in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-dataprovider

In my TestNG test, I am using a DataProvider that returns an Iterator object, but when I run the test, I am getting an error. Could someone please explain why this is wrong and what I should do to fix it?

**Eclipse Version:**

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200
```

**Java Version**

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

**Data Provider**

```
  @DataProvider(name = "SmokeTestData", parallel = true)
public Iterator<SmokeTestData> smokeTestData(ITestContext context) {
    String fileName = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("filename");
    int numberOfTests = SmokeTestData.getNumberOfTests(fileName, true);
    SmokeTestData[] testSuiteData = new SmokeTestData[numberOfTests];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTests; i++) {
        testSuiteData[i-1] = new SmokeTestData(fileName, i);
    }
    return (Stream.of(testSuiteData)).iterator();
}
```

**Test**

```
 @Test(description = "Smoke Test", dataProvider = "SmokeTestData", groups =
        {"SmokeTest"})
@Description("Smoke Test")
@Severity(SeverityLevel.NORMAL)
public void smokeTest(SmokeTestData smokeTestData) {
    selectEnv(smokeTestData.getUrl());
    loginPage.get().smoketest(smokeTestData.getEnvironment(), smokeTestData.getEmail(), smokeTestData.getPassword());
    serviceAvailabilityPage.get().smoketest();
    referralRequestStatusPage.get().smoketest();
}
```

**Data**

```
Environment,Url,Email,Password
DE,https://somedomain.com/index.php/login,user@somedomain.com,somePW!1
IN,https://somedomain.com/index.php/login,user@somedomain.com,somePW!1
NM,https://somedomain.com/index.php/login,user@somedomain.com,somePW!1
MI,https://somedomain.com/index.php/login,user@somedomain.com,somePW!1
NV,https://somedomain.com/index.php/login,user@somedomain.com,somePW!1
AK,https://somedomain.com/index.php/login,user@somedomain.com,somePW!1
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: data.SmokeTestData cannot be cast to java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object;
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1102)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Thank you for any help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by uninstalling Eclipse completely including the following folders and emptying trash.

- ~/.eclipse
- ~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.platform.ide
- ~/Library/Saved Application State/org.eclipse.platform.ide.savedState
- ~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.platform.ide.plist

And then installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version 2018-09 and TestNG plugin.